# Passing data to controller using jQuery Json

Tags: jquery, json

I am new to jQuery and Json. I want to pass a value from the dropdown list to controller using jQuery and Json, but whatever I do I am getting an error message.

This is my code:

VIEW

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ACT_NO").change(function () {
            var selectedItem = $(this).val();            
            var txt = $("#testID");
            if (selectedItem != null || selectedItem != "")
            {
                $("#testID").replaceWith("VALUE PRESENT");
                $("#testID1").replaceWith(selectedItem);
            }
            $.ajax({
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify({ id: $("#ACT_NO").val() }),
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("matterdict/getActionDesc")',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('successful');
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve data.');                    
                }
            });
        });
        $("#ACT_NO").change(function () {
            $("#testID").replaceWith("successful");
        });
    });

</script>
```

here ACT_NO is the ID of the DDL

My controller code

```
public JsonResult getActionDesc(int act_no)
{
            IEnumerable<string> result = newOps.getAction(act_no);
            return Json(new SelectList(result));
}
```

I am not sure what's wrong with my code, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while receiving the data in controller page, we should get the value of json id by using same attribute name which we sent via json with corresponding data type.

in here, you have sent 'id' as attribute name in json while send it via ajax post and use the same 'id' in controller to get that value.

```
    public JsonResult getActionDesc(int id)
    {
        ------
    }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion ,but it is still not working.I am still getting the error

Comment: what error you are getting ? whether it triggers the server side action or not in your end ? @user_19240589

Comment: thanks for help . Like you suggested I changed the variable and the datatype to string instead of int. when I debugged my script I noticed  that the URL that I was setting was wrong . Thanks again..